# Conversion between FFT & ASD

Tags: frequency-spectrum

I have raw data in units of time (sec) vs acceleration (g). I can convert to to the frequency domain, but am unclear about conversion from an FFT to ASD.

For a bandwidth f1 -> f2 is it the sum or average of the squares?:

*Where g1 is the amplitude at f1 * sqrt(2)

1. $G_\text{rms}^2/\text{Hz} = \frac{\left(\sum\left(g_1^2 + g_o^2 + \cdots+ g_2^2\right)\right)^2}{f_2 - f_1}$
2. $G_\text{rms}^2/\text{Hz} =\frac{\text{mean}\left({g_1^2 + g_o^2 +\cdots+ g_2^2}\right)^2}{f_2-f_1}$

Comment: excuse my ignorance on the topic, but what is ASD?

Comment: also notice that the only difference between your two equations is a factor of $N$, with $N$ being the number of $g_?$ that there are.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - ASD is acceleration spectral density which is used in characterizing vibration profiles. Thanks for fixing the formatting!

Comment: Yes - it is just a difference in **N**, but I am not sure which way it should go.